# ¿Alguien podría explicarme esta función en python?

Tags: python

Estoy estudiando algo de python, pero me encontré con esta función que normaliza los datos en una lista, sin embargo no entiendo como itera cada elemento de norm.

Esta es la línea. Recibe únicamente a lista que es una lista de elementos numéricos.

```
norm=[i/sum(lista) for i in lista]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te la traduzco:

```
norm = []  # Generamos una nueva lista vacía
total = sum(lista)  # Esto suma los valores de toda la lista
for element in lista:  # Iteramos por cada elemento de la lista
    calculado = element / total  # Y lo dividimos por el total
    norm.append(calculado)  # Y añadimos ese nuevo elemento calculado a la nueva lista (norm)
```

Veras que si ahora haces un `print(norm)` el resultado debería ser el mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ah justo hemos respondido a la vez jaja. Pero sí, las List Comprehensions son bastantes útiles si lo que quieres es algo sencillo y evitarte escribir mucho código innecesario, y aparte suelen ser más rápidas.

Answer (score 0):

Vale investigando otro poco lo encontré. La técnica se llama list comprehensions. Lo que hace es manejar la siguiente sintáxis:

```
A=[B for i in lista]
```

Donde B puede ser la misma i o alguna operación a realizar con i, que es la variable que toma un valor de la lista a la vez por cada iteración.

En mi ejemplo i toma los valores de la lista y el argumento B hace la operación i/sum(lista) y va guardando el valor de dicha operación por cada iteración.

Otro ejemplo:

```
#Metodo tradicional
lista = []
for letra in 'casa':
  lista.append(letra)
print(lista)

# Con list comprehensions
lista = [letra for letra in 'casa']
print(lista)
```

donde el resultado de ambas funciones es ['c', 'a', 's', 'a'].